# Windows WLAN AutoConfig Service and Wirelss Configuration Utility stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

I bought and HP15 laptop in November and it came loaded with Win8, which I did not want so I partitioned the drive and installed Win7 64bit, found the appropriate drivers and have been using the laptop since. 2 days ago, the wireless configuration utility stopped recognizing wireless networks and after trying to reinstall the driver, try another driver it still does not work and will not recognize any wireless networks like it did for ~3 months. System Restore did not work either. The card does still work when I boot to the OE win8 partition.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to function without a reimage? The OS is Win7 64bit and the wireless card is an onboard Realtek 8188EE. I'm at a loss as to how to get this to cooperate, maybe a 3rd party wireless management tool?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did I understand correctly: It worked, but - suddenly - it stopped working?

Comment: Yes, it worked for about 3 months and then stopped in the middle of use, no obvious events to cause it, no updates done at the time, nothing.

Comment: Since it works when using win8, there shouldn't be a hardware problem. The only reason I can imaging is actually some software-"update", changed settings, whatever. I'd try reinstalling wifi drivers: download them from manufacturer webpage and load them dierctly in hardware manager.

Comment: I've done that already, multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I did a system file reinstall where all settings and software are kept, but the OS files are reinstalled and that fixed it. I still do not have the wireless connection icon in the system tray but it is working without a complete reimage now.